# Web Crawler creates a lot of sessions

Tags: cache, session, robots.txt, crawler

I recently noted that the table `core_session` is growing very fast ( +400MB ) I'm quite sure this is something abnormal.

- I have truncated it but after a couple of days, It is again very big.
- If I switch to file systems backend the problem persists
- I found out that about every second I get a new session

**Test:**

The session is behaving correctly:
I performed some test on our staging server ( protected by .htaccess ):

- So far everything looks working fine: 1 access produce 1 session.

**Cause:**
On live site *online customer* (Magento backend) shows about 500 customers ( I think each row represent open sessions):

- Some IP address are shown multiple times (20/30)
- Checking those IP with https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipWhoisLookupResult I found out they are from GOOGLE/Microsoft.

eureka: **Bots/Crawlers do not store cookies so everytime the access to the site they produce a new session**

**Questions:**

- Is it normal those bots do 100/200 access/session each?
- How can I limit the related session issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**BOT & SESSION**
I'm not sure Bot needs sessions and the answer may be different for every bot for sure they don't store a cookie so it is no possible to re-use the old session matching the session ID stored in the client cookie.

**How other E-Commerce fix this**
Prestashop folks revolved the problem in [this way](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/2aadfc1c6f4606272aff9740930f9de06748466b/classes/Connection.php#L118):

- Assigning to the bots the old sessions using the IP address to match the old session.

Unfortunately, Magento doesn't store the IP along with the session ID, I guess this is because Magento support more backend for session (files, DB, Redis)

**How I fixed it**
There is another question actually there is a similar question [Magento generating aprox 20 session files per minute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18276/magento-generating-aprox-20-session-files-per-minute)
I used the information in the old question to create a solution that integrates the Prestashop approach while it is still compatible with all Magento session backend

All the Magento session magic happens here: `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php`
This is an `abstract` that is extended by all the other session models, so you cannot simply `rewrite` it but only copy it in **/local/**`Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php`.

So the below code do 3 things:

1. It adds a more comprehensive list of bot
2. Check if the client is a bot
3. in that case, it calculates the session using the IP of the client and forces this id.

**In short**
Add the following methods to your copy of `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien`

```
public function isBot()
    {
        $isbot = false;
        $bot_regex = '/BotLink|bingbot|AhrefsBot|ahoy|AlkalineBOT|anthill|appie|arale|araneo|AraybOt|ariadne|arks|ATN_Worldwide|Atomz|bbot|Bjaaland|Ukonline|borg\-bot\/0\.9|boxseabot|bspider|calif|christcrawler|CMC\/0\.01|combine|confuzzledbot|CoolBot|cosmos|Internet Cruiser Robot|cusco|cyberspyder|cydralspider|desertrealm, desert realm|digger|DIIbot|grabber|downloadexpress|DragonBot|dwcp|ecollector|ebiness|elfinbot|esculapio|esther|fastcrawler|FDSE|FELIX IDE|ESI|fido|H�m�h�kki|KIT\-Fireball|fouineur|Freecrawl|gammaSpider|gazz|gcreep|golem|googlebot|griffon|Gromit|gulliver|gulper|hambot|havIndex|hotwired|htdig|iajabot|INGRID\/0\.1|Informant|InfoSpiders|inspectorwww|irobot|Iron33|JBot|jcrawler|Teoma|Jeeves|jobo|image\.kapsi\.net|KDD\-Explorer|ko_yappo_robot|label\-grabber|larbin|legs|Linkidator|linkwalker|Lockon|logo_gif_crawler|marvin|mattie|mediafox|MerzScope|NEC\-MeshExplorer|MindCrawler|udmsearch|moget|Motor|msnbot|muncher|muninn|MuscatFerret|MwdSearch|sharp\-info\-agent|WebMechanic|NetScoop|newscan\-online|ObjectsSearch|Occam|Orbsearch\/1\.0|packrat|pageboy|ParaSite|patric|pegasus|perlcrawler|phpdig|piltdownman|Pimptrain|pjspider|PlumtreeWebAccessor|PortalBSpider|psbot|Getterrobo\-Plus|Raven|RHCS|RixBot|roadrunner|Robbie|robi|RoboCrawl|robofox|Scooter|Search\-AU|searchprocess|Senrigan|Shagseeker|sift|SimBot|Site Valet|skymob|SLCrawler\/2\.0|slurp|ESI|snooper|solbot|speedy|spider_monkey|SpiderBot\/1\.0|spiderline|nil|suke|http:\/\/www\.sygol\.com|tach_bw|TechBOT|templeton|titin|topiclink|UdmSearch|urlck|Valkyrie libwww\-perl|verticrawl|Victoria|void\-bot|Voyager|VWbot_K|crawlpaper|wapspider|WebBandit\/1\.0|webcatcher|T\-H\-U\-N\-D\-E\-R\-S\-T\-O\-N\-E|WebMoose|webquest|webreaper|webs|webspider|WebWalker|wget|winona|whowhere|wlm|WOLP|WWWC|none|XGET|Nederland\.zoek|AISearchBot|woriobot|NetSeer|Nutch|YandexBot|YandexMobileBot|SemrushBot|FatBot|MJ12bot|DotBot|AddThis|baiduspider|m2e/i';
        $userAgent = empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? FALSE : $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $isBot = !$userAgent || preg_match($bot_regex, $userAgent);

        return $isBot;
    }

public function getBotSessionId()
{
    $s = (int)Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure();
    $botIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    return 'bot' . $s . sha1($botIp);
}
```

and change the `getSessionId()` in this way

```
public function setSessionId($id = null)
    {
        if (!is_null($id) && preg_match('#^[0-9a-zA-Z,-]+$#', $id)) {
            session_id($id);
        } elseif ($this->isBot()) {
            $this->setSessionId($this->getBotSessionId());
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

You may also want to change the behavior in case the bot access via HTTPS inside `start()` when you see `session_regenerate_id(false);`

```
                if (!$this->isBot()) {
                session_regenerate_id(false);
            }
```

**Note**
The bot session Id will be a little longer, [sha1 function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php):

> returned value is a 40-character hexadecimal number

this should not be a problem since [PHP allows session to be 128 character long](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php#116836)

Comment: This is an ingenious solution, I did give the other one you linked to a try first but the downside is Google etc get 500 errors when crawling, this solution is the best of both worlds, thanks!

Comment: See alto this issue if you want to save your SSD https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63295/how-to-disable-report-viewed-products-in-magento#

Comment: I am struggling with the same. I was just wondering where to put the last piece of code


`if (!$this->isBot()) {
                session_regenerate_id(false);
            }`